# std::map out_of_range exception not being caught

Tags: c++, exception

I'm using the asio networking library. I'm seeing a very strange behaviour where the debugger tells me that the call to std::map::at() throws an out_of_range exception, however I have catch block to catch precisely that type of exception!

The map in question is this:

```
/*Both of these maps are global variables in the namespace cloud*/
map<string, weak_ptr<session> > cloud::services;
map<string, vector<weak_ptr<session> > > cloud::subscribed; //this one
```

And the code that's throwing the exception is this:

```
void session::subscribirse(std::string a_which)
{
  try
  {
    //We obtain a reference to the group of sockets subscribed to this service name
    vector<weak_ptr<session>>& grupo = cloud::subscribed.at(a_which);   //HERE
    grupo.emplace_back(shared_from_this() );
  }
  catch(out_of_range& e) //The group didn't exist (no-one had subscribed to it yet)
  {
    vector<weak_ptr<session>> new_group;
    new_group.emplace_back(shared_from_this());
    cloud::subscribed.emplace(make_pair(a_which, new_group));
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    cout << "unexpected exception during subscribe\n";
  }
  subscriptions_.emplace_back(a_which);
  consumed_ = true;
}
```

Could the catch-block be rethrowing and the debugger not being capable of detecting that? (I really don't think so).

Sorry if question is not clear, I've spent the last 6 hours and I'm feeling desperate.

Comment: From the code shown here, I would say that the `catch` block should work. There is nothing in the `catch` block that could rethrow `std::out_of_range`.

Comment: Well. Check namespace collisions (spell it out as `catch (::std::out_of_range const&e)` e.g.). Next up, rebuild every part of the program and dependencies with _exactly_ the same compiler flags. Make sure `nube::suscritos` is _actually_ of type `::std::map<...>`

Comment: @JamesPoag makes a valid point: how certain are you that your assumptions are valid? Can you debug trace when compiling without optimization?

Comment: Also try a `catch(std::exception& e2)` between your two existing catches, and print out `e2.what()`.

Comment: Changing out_of_range& to std::out_of_range const& did make a difference, the exception gets caught now. Was it ignoring the exception thrown because I was catching non-const exceptions? And why did (...) not catch it?

Comment: Sigh... nevermind, the error still appeared after data from a serial port came to the socket, so probably garbage values corrupt somehow the logic my program uses. Anyway, using `find()` to determine if value is present is not subject to those errors, and is by far the best solution. Thanks for your time, though I'm still perplexed at that strange behavior.

Comment: Oh. In that case, your whole question is misguided. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[]` operator will insert an empty value if it doesn't already exist and doesn't throw.

```
cloud::subscribed[a_which].emplace_back(shared_from_this() );
```

You can check for the existence of a `key` using `find()`:

```
if(cloud::subscribed.find(a_which) != cloud::subscribed.end())
```

---

Finally, how certain are you that it's throwing an out of bounds exception and not another exception?

Comment: "How certain?" - About [5/7 prolly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) o.O

Comment: I can see how the phrasing has confused you. Yes, at() throws `out of bounds`, but if the other catch is being triggered, then how certain are you that it's an `out of bounds` exception?  There is more code in the `try` block than dreamt of [...], Horatio.

Comment: @JamesPoag Thanks for the tip James, the alternative using `find()` is more clear and easier to maintain. Sehe's suggestion to explicitly name `std::out_of_range const&` caused the exceptions to be caught. I'm still puzzled since (...) is supposed to catch everything. I'm doing a lot of low level IO so maybe this was undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Turambar you are clearly seeing namespace collisions/hiding there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice